# I'm having an infinite loop with React hooks and I'm not sure why

Tags: reactjs, typescript

https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-wildflower-764w4

Basically what I'm trying to do is the following:

I have a server validation function I've mocked in the example. I'd like to retain state locally so that the input shows the value being typed in. When it's validated I want it to trigger the onChange event.

But somehow I get an infinite loop and I dont understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an infinite loop, because you're passing an `onChange` property such way:

```
onChange={(v) => setMap((m) => ({ ...m, [key]: v }))}
```

Which means, that the reference of `props.onChange` will be changed every time. So, the `useEffect` inside `AddressInput` will be called every render.

In turn, the `useEffect` calls `props.onChange()`, which triggers the same `useEffect`, and the cycle repeats over and over.

To avoid an infinite loop, you need to keep a reference of a function type property using the `useCallback` hook.